# Can we debug a program in cmd rather than in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

In Visual Studio 2015 IDE, we can debug a C# or C or C++ program.

Without the IDE, in cmd instead, how can we debug a program? Thanks.

Comment: are you actually want to debug from command line or just in different tools than VS?

Answer (score 1):

The [CLR debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxbks7z.aspx) or [MDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx) is the tool I used to debug app in command line. But they also have some limitations more or less.

For example, not all projects/developing languages are supported by them.

Other workaround is that you could think about using other Editor instead of the CMD if you don't have the VS Environment like the VC code or the Windbug or others.

Comment: @Tim, whether two command line tools provided the useful information? If possible, I suggest you use certain editor directly like VS, VS code or windbg, it would be much more easy and convenient, and it has more features. Of course, not have to use the VS IDE:), any debugging issue, feel free to share it.